# PHP page setting variable to command output and comparing to string

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec

I'm creating a PHP page that uses an `if` statement to compare the value of a shell script to a string, but it alway seems to be false:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/sbin/genarts_server_status');
echo $output
if($output == "UP")
{
   echo 'Server is up';
} else {
   echo 'Server is down';
}
?>
```

Line 3 is simply echoing the value of the variable and that echo does correctly return "UP", but the comparison of the variable to the "UP" string returns false and therefore echoes "Server is down".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Missing `;` in `echo $output`?!

Comment: Try doing: `if (trim($output) == 'UP')` to trim away any potential white spaces (like space, new line etc).